# $\log^2(x-1)$ vs. $\log(x-1)^2$

Tags: calculus

> Solve for $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$:
>
> $$\log^2(x-1) - \log(x-1)^2 = 0$$

If I make the first one $x$ and the second one $y$, I have that $x = y$, and so the solution should be $x \in\, ]0;+\infty[$ or $\mathbb{R+}$

However, my book says the solution is $x =2 \lor x=101$.

Did I miss something? I copied the problem as it is.

Comment: OHH!!!!  My bad.  Thanks Zachary.

Comment: You missed something.  $\log^2 (x-1)$ means $ [ \log(x-1)]^2$. The other one means $\log [ (x-1)^2 ]$. If $x$ is, say, 11, the first is the square of $\log 10$, which is 1; the other is the log of $100$, which is $2$.

Comment: I  suppose it is the decimal logarithm?

Comment: @Bernard I think so

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $u=\log(x-1)$. Then your equation is $u^2-2u=0$, so $u(u-2)=0$ so $u=0$ or $u=2$.

If $u=0$ then $\log(x-1)=0$, so $x-1=1$ or $x=2$. If $\log(x-1)=2$ then $x-1=100$ or $x=101$.

Answer (score 4):

Factorise the equation:
$$\log(x-1)[\log(x-1)-2]=0, \text{ whence } \begin{cases}\log(x-1)=0\\\text{or}\\
\log(x-1)=2\end{cases}\iff\begin{cases}x-1=1\\\text{or}\\x-1=10^2.\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 3):

The book probably intends this to be

> Solve for $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$:
>   $$\big[\log(x-1)\big]^2 - \log\big[(x-1)^2\big] = 0$$

This is equivalent to
$$\big[\log(x-1)\big]^2 - 2\log\big[(x-1)\big] = 0$$
which implies that
$$\log(x-1)\big[\log(x-1)-2\big] = 0$$
The solutions should now be obvious!